# How can I generate an automatic weather?

Tags: php, weather

I have to create an automatic weather including rain, snow, clouds, fog and sunny.

Depending on the season I need to set a percentage for all weather: the forecast will be updated 3 or 4 times during a day.

Example:
Winter | Rain: 30% Snow: 30% Sunny: 10% Cloudy: 10%, Fog: 20%

I do not know how to implement a random condition based on percentages. Some help?

Many thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is exactly. Are you unsure abount how to distribute the percentages?

Comment: So, is the basic problem "how to randomly divide 100% into 5 parts?"

Comment: @Pekka 
I just corrected the percentage, I forgot a couple of numbers

@Piskvor
I think so, the problem is determining which condition will be set based on the percentage of "successful".

Comment: @Diego I still don't understand what you need. Do you need "Wintery" sets with minimal random variations of your Winter example, like 29% 27% 14% 9% and 21%? Or do you need entirely different sets? More examples would be helpful I think

Comment: @Pekka I need different sets, they are chosen by me based on what the owner wants to play. The problem is that I do not know how to write the script, how to determine the climatic conditions according to the percentages.

Comment: @Diego: One problem here is that "generate" suggests that you are trying to make *fake* numbers (possibly ones that look real) for a game or something. The answer you accepted below is how to "get predictions" for *real* weather from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use:

```
$location = 'Rome';
$document = file_get_contents(str_replace(" ", "+", "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=".$location));
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($document); 
echo "$location: ".$xml->temp_c."&deg; C";
```

Just take a look on the XML and see what data you have available.

**EDIT**

I didn't understand what the OP wanted the first time. Basically, it's even easier.

```
$weather = mt_rand(0,100);
$season = 'winter';
switch($season) {
    case 'winter': {
        if ($weather < 30) {
            $output = 'Rainy';
        } else if ($weather >=30 && $weather < 60) {
            $output = 'Snowy';
        }
        // goes on on the same ideea of testing the value of $weather
        break;
    }
    // other seasons 
} 

echo $output;
```

What I suggest tough, is to keep your values in arrays (for example the seasons) as well as the values for chances to have one type of weather or another.

```
array (
   [winter] => array (
       [30] => 'Rainy',
       [60] => 'Snowy',
       ... // the other chances of weather
   ),
   [spring] => array (
       ...
   ), 
   ... // and so on
)
```

Use `mt_rand(0,100)` to get a random value and the array above to determine the weather.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

The problem is that I have to implement a random condition based on percentages, not using api.

I can not understand, once I determined the season, how to use percentages to determine the condition until the next weather update.

Like this:

in Winter | Rain: 30% Snow: 30% Sunny: 10% Cloudy: 10%, Fog: 20%
in Autumn | Rain: 20% Snow: 0% Sunny: 30% Cloudy: 40%, Fog: 10%

With these parameters, the script should produce a weather condition.

Comment: Oh, so basically, you have 30% chances of rain, 30% chances of snow, 10% chances of sun, 10% chances of clouds and 20% chances of fog in the winter for example?

Comment: @Diego I edited my response above according to the requirements

Comment: @Claudiu

Ok, Thanks. I just have created a script like your example.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by **Claudiu**  but if you want to view with Fahrenheit (F) that possible example Below:

```
 <?php
 $location = 'Washington';
 $document = file_get_contents(str_replace(" ", "+", "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=" . $location));
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($document);
 echo $xml->temp_f . "&deg; F";
 ?>
```